# cmake with rosserial problem

Tags: arduino, rosserial, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I edited the CMakeLists.txt as directed, and got the (expected) error: -- The arduino sdk path is ARDUINO_SDK_PATH-NOTFOUND
-- Could NOT find Arduino (missing:  ARDUINO_SDK_PATH ARDUINO_SDK_VERSION)

I set the ARDUINO_SDK_PATH to ~/Downloads/arduino-1.0 where the IDE lies using set(ARDUINO_SDK_PATH ~/Downloads/arduino-1.0/).

Now I'm getting: -- Could NOT find Arduino (missing:  ARDUINO_SDK_VERSION)

what do I have to set ARDUINO_SDK_VERSION as??

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30022/cmake-with-rosserial-problem/) by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

set(ARDUINO_SDK_VERSION 1.0)

---

Originally posted by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) with karma: 115 on 2012-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1